# Can I store stuff at the Goodsprings Schoolhouse?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

It's still a bit early for me to have my own home in New Vegas, but at the same time I don't want to carry everything around all the time -- kind of puts a damper on how much loot you can bring back!

Is it safe to store my loot in the Goodsprings schoolhouse? Will it stay, or will it eventually disappear after x amount of in-game time or x number of save/load cycles?

Comment: Can't you save it, put your stuff inside, then walk outside and rest for a loooong while to test it out?

Comment: I suppose, but I'd rather play the game than spend 20 or 30 minutes resting 24 hours at a time to find out.

Comment: IIRC in fallout stuff put into a container stayed there. Most likely the same with new vegas, I just started so not sure yet

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In New Vegas, as in Fallout 3, if a container is marked 'respawn' the contents will be overwritten every 3 in-game days with whatever is the default for the container type. This is why it's generally unwise to leave anything you may want to save in a random container.

However all the containers in the Goodsprings Schoolhouse are not marked as respawning containers, so it should be safe to store any excess loot there.

Comment: How can you tell if a container is marked as respawning?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know of an easy way to check in-game. I used the GECK (the modification tools provided by Bethesda) to check the containers for the 'respawn' flag.

Answer (score 4):

I personally use the Garbage Dumpster next to the Goodsprings store.  Its quick, right next to the Express Mail machine, and I have not had it respawn on me, saves me a walk anywhere, and I can just fast travel to Goodsprings to drop stuff off.  I have a crapload of stuff in there.

Comment: Alternately, you can just use the Mojave Express mailboxes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I use the building in the middle of Goodsprings where the old guy lives. Multiple containers means different classification of stuff to prevent lag due to lengthy inventory lists, and those containers never respawn either.

Answer (score 1):

In Goodsprings, between the Saloon and the General Store are 4 XXX crates. You can move and stack these next to the bench's. They are safe to store items in.
As you travel; ammo, first aid, and tool boxes are always safe. In a pinch, the nuke-cola machines are also safe.
Later, once you arrive at the Lucky 38, turn left when you first enter and under the stairwell is an area with a multitude of lockers and safes. All are safe to store items and with so many you can organize them as you like.
Note: Do not use the other containers in this area; suitcase, cash registers, etc. These are not confirmed safe.
In the world, lockers (other than those mentioned above), file cabinets, metal boxes, garbage cans, and most garbage dumpsters are never safe.