# Can you get your own house?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I was wondering if you can get your own house in Fallout: New Vegas like you did in Fallout 3?

Comment: Maybe you should add if you want a spoiler-free answer or not. I assumed you don't want any spoilers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get your own place if you follow the main quest. For this one you can also buy upgrades.

There is an earlier opportunity to rent a motel room (forever).

Comment: Additionally, and this is very useful early-game when you might not want to spend caps on a room, you can store items pretty much indefinitely at [The Goodsprings Schoolhouse](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9578/can-i-store-stuff-at-the-goodsprings-schoolhouse)

Comment: @John : other safe places in Goodsprings are the boxes between the store and the saloon, or inside the Doc's place.  (wih the boxes being convenient to stash stuff right near the workbench and reloading bench ... if only there were a campfire nearby, too)

Comment: @Joe: There's a campfire not far away, I think at the Goodsprings Source?

Comment: @John : yeah, it's just a little bit of a hike, so not good when you want to finally go and process the 300lb of dirty water and 500 lbs of meat you've slowly collected.  (I need to get that ability to fast travel while overloaded perk)

Comment: @Joe: I got that one. Ironically, I haven't used it yet ...

Answer (score 10):

There are two 'homes'. When you reach Novac, there is a Motel room you can rent, which is safe to store stuff and rest in, and if you complete the quest [One for My Baby](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/One_for_My_Baby) by accusing the actual perpetrator, you'll receive it permanently at no charge.

Further along the main quest, once you reach The Strip, you'll be given access to the Presidential Suite at the [Lucky 38](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lucky_38) Hotel and Casino. This functions more like the house you gained in FO3, in that when you dismiss companions, you can have them wait for you in the Suite, and you can purchase various 'upgrades' to add more style and functionality to the apartment. There are also several mods that add additional crafting resources or other customizations, if you're playing on the PC.

Comment: Also, snowglobes you collect are in your room in the Lucky 38, making it much like the homes in Fallout 3 (bobbleheads)

Comment: The Tops Presidential Suite (*not* the high roller suite) is also safe to store items in, once you have Benny's key.

Answer (score 3):

You also get a room for free at the Wrangler once you have collected every debt and taken care of the previous debt collector (which is the last task of that quest).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Victor's shack in Good Springs: that's the first house you can get. You've got a bed to sleep in, a sink which is purified, a oven to store your aids, a couple of ammo boxes to store weapons and ammo, and also a desk to store your miscellaneous stuff. It's also free of charge; there's no need to rent a motel room.

Answer (score 1):

Get in a house, kill whoever is in there, and just stash your stuff there.

For example:

> Kill Victor (you are gonna do it anyway in the storyline, unless you are the kind of guy that does anything you're told and be House's dog) and take his shack.

Also, there are several abandoned places which would do just fine.

Comment: That's great advice if you want to lose all of your stuff to cell resets.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is find Harper's Shack. It's just north and east of hidden springs. It has a campfire outside for crafting, a reloading bench, a workbench, lockers, storage boxes and a bed. The only downside is it's near a deathclaw cave. Easily avoidable and/or assaulted

Answer (score 0):

The Jean Sky Diving shack, down the road from Goodsprings, is also a good storage house with only two Powder Gangers and some Bloatflies out back.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an unoccupied shack right next to a burial ground near Good Springs. The only downside is there are a small portion of Radscorpians.

Answer (score 0):

There is a general store in Nipton, inside there is a harmless powder ganger. Kill him. The store contains a bed and a safe you can put your stuff in.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 places that i know of,

- the Penthouse Suit inside the Lucky 38 Hotel and Casino provided by Mr House when you meet him, you can customize by buying stuff
- The Brotherhood of Steel Safehouse which you get from doing quests for them, since i always opt to not blow them up i have no idea if you still keep it after you get rid of them.

if your on PC there's ofcause Mods, 2 that i use is

**Underground Hideout** - puts a manhole in Bonnie Springs, you can do a quest to get the key or opt to skip it, inside it has a garden for growing food, water purifier, clean water sources mannequins, weapon and ammo sorter/storage, a teleporter and the terminal inside allow you to get delivery from the Crimson Caravan. you all get this sledge hammer which allows you to move the manhole so it's mobile somewhat.

there is also a setting to use the Reactor which powers the place, having the setting on means every light consumes power and the reactor needs to be refueled with some Isotope which you can buy for a couple thousand caps or you can make it using the ammo press and power cells, having every light on means the reactor uses fuel quicker but if you just have light on for the main area and the armory one isotope last a month and a few snow globes you can have the reactor fueled for quite a long time.

**Vault-Tech Mobile Home** this adds a man holes near a couple of Powder Ganger camps just a bit west of Good Springs, inside is a Vault-Tech Facility which after searching, hacking, and blowing up robots gets you a trailer, inside it has all you need plus the computer allows you to change the internal design and move the trailer to any key place which means from the beginning you can zoom right off to places like Nellis Air force Base and in doesn't take time so in hardcore you Sleep, Food and Water needs wont increase.

the facility also have truck loads of rations which if you play hardcore means you don't have to worry about food

both mods have the basics, beds, containers where you can store your stuff, toilets to drink from, and both mods put the home in the map for fast travel. i use the Underground Hideout as my main base only in Good psrings and use the Mobile Home to jump only to places i can fast travel to cut down on travel time to others nearby