# Where are good home base sites in Fallout: New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Where are some good places to set up a home base in Fallout: New Vegas?

My criteria for "good" are as follows:

- Permanent (non-resetting) storage containers, the more the better
- Quick to get to from a fast travel location
- Quick to get to a place where you can fast travel away
- Nearby access to fire, reloading bench, and/or workbench for crafting
- Nearby courier access (would be a nice to have)
- Accessible as early as possible (with a low level)

This question ([Can you get your own house in Fallout: New Vegas?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/can-you-get-your-own-house-in-fallout-new-vegas)) mentions three places, but none of them really meet my criteria. The locations don't have to be a place that is officially *yours*, just one that you can claim and use without having to fight your way in and out.

In the past I've used the [Goodsprings Schoolhouse](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Goodsprings_Schoolhouse), but it's a long walk from the fast travel spot to it, and it's a long walk from it to any crafting places.

Comment: if you have the PC version you could always download a mod that adds a player house with all the crafting necessities and a fast travel location

Comment: I used the hotel room at Novac.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Goodsprings has most of what you're looking for, I didn't use the school house, instead I used the boxes next to where you took target practice, both work benches are there. AFAIK you only need 1 box to store a lot of stuff. If it's because of sorting, well you can click on the top of your inventory window, click on the "Items" in the title bar, that will give you different types of sorts.[image]

Comment: You can sort?! You just blew my mind. And I never thought of trying those boxes.

Comment: Yep I didn't know for a long time too :) found it on the wiki iirc

Comment: Any way to sort on consoles?

Comment: There's actually no need to sort. In the location we're talking about, along the wall of the general store, there are at least 4 usable crates (and/or barrels?) as I recall. I use one for crafting ingredients, one for armor, one for weapons, and one for healing/buffing items. I've looked all over for a better place, and except for the lack of a campfire the general store is ideal.

Answer (score 4):

Harpers Shack- Has plenty of room to store items, has a; work bench, reloading bench, campfire, bed, table, and the only thing to worry about is being near a viper camp, they do not bother you because they are normally killed by passing NCR/legion squads and sometimes golden geckos.

Comment: This is a good suggestion in general, but I wouldn't recommend it for low-level characters. Because of its proximity to Dead Wind Cavern, you sometimes pick up one or more deathclaws just outside, and if you try to escape by running into the shack they'll sometimes follow you inside. Also, according to Wikia, Vipers will sometimes spawn inside of the shack. (http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Harper%27s_shack)

Answer (score 4):

I always use the hotel room in Novac as my base of operations.  Novac's pretty close to the start of the game (long before I venture out far enough to need additional storage).  It's fast to get in and out of the room, there's a doctor nearby for any radiation or injury issues, Cliff Briscoe is a decent vendor, and there's plenty of storage.  Crafting is available at the gas station just outside the hotel perimeter.

If you've got Old World Blues, using The Sink as a base of operations is also pretty decent.  The Transportalponder will take you there from pretty much any outdoor location, even if you're overburdened (without the fast travel while overburdened perk!).  It's loaded to the gills with every crafting station possible, plus a number of ways to disassemble junk items into useful crafting materials.  The one major downside is that you can't go there with companions - you'll have to dismiss anyone following you before entering and go pick them up after leaving.

Answer (score 3):

I use an empty trailer in Goodsprings.  (yes, I now live in a trailer)

It has a bed and a box, and it's relatively close to a workbench, reloading bench, and the post box.  The only thing you need to walk a bit for is a fire.

If you've run into the Caravan deck bug where new cards are not automatically put into  your deck, you'll probably want access to a second, empty container.  Just put all your cards into the box, leave, then come back and take all.

Answer (score 2):

I've split this idea. You can keep workbench-related items in the XXX box(es) beside the benches in Goodsprings, and then use a different place for the campfire-related crafting. So far, I've been using the Powder Gangers south camp (the one under/beside the freight car in the middle of nowhere), which has a campfire just a few yards from the quick-travel spawn point. There's never anyone there (unless you take the quest from the Power Ganger's leader to knock off his rival), and there are a couple of metal boxes for storing excess supply.

I wish I could use the Fiends' camp site on the edge of the quarry. When you quick travel to that location, you're standing RIGHT NEXT to a campfire, and there's a metal box right beside the fire. Unfortunately, for some reason, you can't access that box. :-(

I wish they'd put a place in one of the eventual DLC's that would meet all of your criteria!

Comment: They did - The Sink, in the Old World Blues DLC, only misses the courier drop boxes and the low-level access. It is, on my experience, the best place to craft items, though.

Answer (score 1):

Containers near postbox in Goodsprings worked well for me during whole game. Just remember to quicksave before opening them (in case you press A accidentally).

Comment: Using A as both "Accept" for transferring large quantities of items **and** "Take All" is the single worst design decision in that game.

Comment: @Javadoc I thought I was the only one to rage over that :)

Answer (score 1):

I just make my home-base inside the vaults I clear out. It takes a lot of work, but I love having a room in a big, nice vault. (Vault 11 for example.)

Answer (score 1):

The brotherhood of the steel has a safehouse that they let you have after some part of the mission. It has everything except a fire - some power armor, a laser gatling gun and several other power weapons. The downsides are that there's no fire and it's definitely not for low level players.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Primm sheriff's office in Primm early on the game after saving Deputy Beagle and programming Primm Slim to be the sheriff. Then later on I used Raul's shack. I kept Raul there to do my repair (since he is not a great companion) Its easy to do Raul's companion quest. Gave him good armor and weapon then dismissed him to his shack to repair my stuff.

Comment: I dont store ammunition related items in a storage box... The Courrier can carry as much as you want since they're weightless. ;-)

Comment: if you turn on hardcore then ammunition weighs something so you'll need to store them as well

Answer (score 0):

There is an NCR safehouse I use. I accessed it with console commands. It has all of your criteria except you need console commands but I **think** there might be a fire near by so try it out.

Comment: What console commands did you use?